# Lock Hard drive partition using ubuntu password

Tags: password, lock

i want to use my ubuntu password , to lock a hard partition with it can i ?!

use my password so no one else can acess type of partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is [encrypting it](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+encrypt+hard+drive+ubuntu), because even if you make Ubuntu ask for a password to access it, anyone can still boot up another operating system Live CD and access it.

If you're not that worried than simply creating a good root password is enough, since mounting devices require root password.

That's only about accessing the partition. Now about wiping your data there isn't much you can do but preventing your computer to be physically accessed by someone else, since anyone can simply boot up a GParted live CD or a live CD of any other partitioning program or operating system and wipe your hard drive, or just put it on fire or something.

Comment: any type for terminal code for a program or name ?

Comment: When you install Ubuntu there is an option `Full Disk Encryption`. I do not encrypt my disk so I cannot personally recommend anything, but there is a guide from help.ubuntu.com [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto) and TrueCrypt seems to be the recommended software -- I never used it, though.